# Applescript hide prompts in photoshop

Tags: applescript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Anyone know if there is a command to hide prompts in applescript. I know in Illustrator you use the following:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set user interaction level to never interact
    set user interaction level to interact with all
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop CS5, you can do this:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
    set display dialogs to never
end tell
```

To turn dialogs back on, use:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
    set display dialogs to always
end tell
```

Comment: I am guessing the undo is "set display dialogs to always"?